# Jssor slidsshow fixed in the background

Tags: javascript, css, background, slideshow, jssor

I've followed the advice regarding full screen responsivity and it works great! Now I wonder if it is possible to also keep the slider fixed in the background so that I can scroll my website on top (bootstrap inspired)? Is there a slider option for that or script? z-index and other css option don't seem to work.

Thanks
Niklas

Jssor I tried your advice without success. I've downloaded the latest Jssor and bootstrap. I'm also using the latest from .net framework. Please have a look at a test site I've done with the basic from the Jssor bootstrap download. http://exploreme-001-site1.smarterasp.net/

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please check this test site http://exploreme-001-site1.smarterasp.net/

Answer (score 0):

It should work, please just try.

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;
$("#slider1_container").css("position", "fixed");
```

Comment: Jssor I'm afraid it didn't help. Here is a test site I've done from the lastest Jssor.zip. I've tried to put the additional html inside and outside the Jssor slider. cheers